# XCode IBAction NSButton to show/hide separate image?

Tags: macos, cocoa, ibaction

I have an IBAction that acts as a toggle switch for one of my functions; how can I make that same button show/hide a separate image depending on the isOn/isOff state?

Here's my code for the toggle function:

```
- (IBAction)toggleFunction:(id)sender;
{
    if( isOn )
    {
        [self stopFunction: (NSButton *)sender];
        isOn = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        [self startFunction: (NSButton *)sender];
        isOff = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **isOn** instead **isOff** I think in Your else.

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)toggleFunction:(id)sender;
{
    if( isOn == YES )
    {
        [self stopFunction: sender];
        isOn = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        [self startFunction: sender];
        isOn = YES;
    }
}
```

** If this not working, say what's wrong. And also try NSLog Your functions to ensure that its called.